# Json string truncated due to "#" character in JSON in window.open()

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my json `{"col1":"val1","col2":"val#","col3":"value"}`

I am, calling window.Open() like this

```
var winW = 0;
var winH = 0;
var winX = 0;
var winY = 0;
var features = 'left=' + winX + ',top=' + winY + ',width=' + winW + ',height=' + winH + ',toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars= 1,resizable=1,visible=0';

var data= JSON.stringify("_data");
var SortOrder = JSON.stringify(_sortOrder);
Window = window.open(methodName+ '?Param=' + data+, null, features);
```

When it goes to is corresponding method, the data after "#" is not there
,What am i missing Please suggest/Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I assume `_"data"` is a typo in your question, as that would be throwing a syntax error.

The `#` character is not permitted within querystring values as it is used to denote the URL fragment. You need to URL encode it:

```
var data = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(foo)).replace(/#/g, '%23');
```

Comment: Yes that was a typo, i am trying with your solution now.